# Can I get ReSharper to generate "overrides" for non-virtual functions?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide, resharper-c++

I know it's not overriding, but I don't know if there's a name for "shadowing" parent functions in child classes. (If there is please tell me)

Example:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    void fn(std::string s);
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void fn(std::string s);
};
```

It's a small issue, but it is rather annoying to have to copy and paste these kinds of function declarations constantly.

ReSharper only lets me generate actual overrides for virtual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to generate a shadowing function in R#. I've filed a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-34440/Generate-hiding-shadowing-functions-inside-a-class) to track upvotes.